# Laravel - different formats for date/time query

Tags: laravel, datetime, date-format, date-formatting

I am learning Laravel and I have some small problem on controllers - when I use DB, the query returns date time without timezone but if I use model, the query returns full datetime.

```
    public function test($switch)
    {
        //return "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.000000Z"
        if ($switch) return Position::select('id','created_at')->orderBy('id')->get();

        // return "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"
        return DB::table('positions')->select('id','created_at')->orderBy('id')->get();
    }
```

Why? What I need to dof I want "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.000000Z" on both cases?
Thanks for solution.

thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `DB::raw`

The following statement will convert the datetime value `created_at` from +00:00 timezone to +10:00 timezone.

You can try this

```
return DB::table('positions')->select(DB::raw('id',CONVERT_TZ('created_at','+00:00','+10:00'))->orderBy('id')->get();
```

you can set your timezone that you wants to convert it

Answer (score 0):

They are the same data, probably just different classes of date and you can always format your date. Laravel utilizes Carbon date library which is excellent and should be used primarily.

If you try to print out your date class with `get_class()` for Eloquent Position created_at, you probably got Carbon and DB::table('positions') created_at, you probably got DateTime and that's why the value looks different (but you still got the same date).

If you want to convert your DateTime to Carbon, you can do

```
$newDate = new \Carbon\Carbon($position->created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anurat,
I realized this fact shortly after sending the previous question.
... but there is another 'issue' - both times are my local time - time in "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.000000Z" is not UTC time as I expected.

I changed my function:

```
    public function test($switch = false)
    {
        $data = Position::selectRaw('id, created_at, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) unix')->orderBy('id')->get();
        
        foreach ($data as $d) {
            $conv = new \DateTime($d->created_at);
            $d->conv = intval($conv->format('U'));
            $d->diff = $d->conv - $d->unix;
            }
        return $data;
    }
```

... and result is

```
    
0   
  id             1
  created_at    "2021-03-18T12:36:59.000000Z"
  unix          1616067419
  conv          1616071019
  diff          3600
```

As you see, the difference is 1 hour (as my timezone offset). Where is a problem?
Thanks.